# Changing open graph meta tags with jQuery

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to dynamically change my `<meta property="og:title" content="CHANGE_ME">` for posting my page with an embedded video on it.

Here's the code I'm using (swapping the `<h1>` and `<title>` works just fine), but I can't get the meta tags to change.

Any help?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.media').html(iframe);
    $.getJSON(mediaDetail, function(data) {
    $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr("content", data.name);
        $('h1').html(data.name);
        $(document).prop('title', data.name + ' | Vipheo');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> trying to dynamically change my `<meta property="og:video"
>   content="CHANGE_ME">`

Try substituting `$("meta[property='og:title']")` selector for `$("meta[property='og:video']")` at `js` to select `meta` element having `property` `og:title`

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <meta property="og:title" content="CHANGE_ME">
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var data = {
        "name": "abc"
      }
      $("meta[property='og:title']").attr("content", data.name);
      console.log($("meta").attr("content"))
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I meant 'title'.

Comment: @user1661677 See updated post. `js` at Question should return expected result